# How do I add a printer to a Netgear router's LAN?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printer, wps

I just bought a HP Deskjet 3050 wireless printer and am trying to connect it to my home network so any connected PC can print to it. The network is "served" from a Netgear WGR614v7 wireless router.

When I go into the printer's WPS settings (from the printer's on-board pushbutton/LCD screen) it gives me two options:

- Push Button
- PIN

I tried the button option, only to discover that my router doesn't actually have a WPS button anywhere on it (if I'm wrong, **please** submit a screenshot or helpful description as to where I can find it on this particular model!)

When I push the "PIN" option, it gives me a PIN and starts counting down from 4 minutes.  It looks like I have that amount of time to register the PIN with my router. I log into my router at 192.168.1.1 but can't seem to find any option that lets me "Add a Device" or "Register a PIN".

How can I get this working?

Comment: According to Netgear, it does: http://www.netgear.com.au/home/products/wirelessrouters/simplesharing/WGR614.aspx#one   What version of the router do you have?

Comment: I don't see where it has a WPS button - only a "wi-fi on/off" button, but its not highlighted or identified anywhere on the image!

Comment: Wow, that printer got some [really bad reviews](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF05a/18972-18972-238444-1142650-410635-4066450.html?dnr=1).

Answer (score 2):

The product page for the [WGR614](http://www.netgear.com.au/home/products/wirelessrouters/simplesharing/WGR614.aspx#one), as MaQleod notes, says:

> Push 'N' Connect using Wi-Fi Protected Setup™ (WPS)1

I couldn't find what the <sup>1</sup> means, but maybe "*not available on all devices*".

### WGR614v10

Assuming you have the WGR614v10, according to [the manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/WGR614v10_SM_03DEC2009.pdf), this is where the WPS button is located:

[image]

The instructions on how to perform the WPS operation are detailed in the manual I linked above.

### WGR614v9 (and below)

Given that the term "WPS" does not appear at all in the [manual for the WGR614v9](http://support.netgear.com/ci/fattach/get/27/1239127755/redirect/1/filename/WGR614v9_UM_14May08.pdf), I would assume the v10 is the earliest revision that introduced the feature.

ps: Here's a nice [emulator for the WGR614v9](http://interface.netgear-forum.com/WGR614v9/).

### So what now?

To my understanding, the setup procedure in your case is quite clear.

You need to connect the printer to a computer and run the wireless setup assistant that came with the printer. If you've lost the driver CD, you may be able to find replacement software on [this portal](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=4066452&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&cc=us).

These are the instructions for Windows, as taken from the [reference guide for the HP Deskjet 3050](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02497863.pdf).

> 1. Click Start > All Programs > HP > HP Deskjet 3050 J610 series, then select Connect new Printer.
> 2. On the Connectivity Choice screen, click Network.
> 3. When prompted to connnect the USB cabel, check the box for USB cable is already connected to continue.
> 4. Use the wireless connection setup wizard. You need to know your wireless network name (SSID) and Wireless Password (WPA passphrase or WEP key) if you are using either of these wireless security methods. In some cases, the software may be able to find these for you.

[image]

During this setup procedure, your wireless networking information should be transferred into the printer.

If that doesn't work, then I have no clue either :)

Comment: Thanks for a really, *really* great answer Oliver.  I feel badly, but I forgot to qualify the version of the router.  This is a v7, so it sounds like (if your assessment is correct), WPS is not a capability of this router. In that case, is there any other way to "jury rig" the router config so that my Windows 7 machine can still see the printer? Thanks again for a great response (+1).

Comment: @AdamTannon I updated my answer to, hopefully, provide some help with your installation.

Answer (score 0):

I would try these steps:

1. Connect your printer to your wired network
2. Take the IP of the printer and navigate to it in your browser
3. Use the web GUI to configure the wireless connection
4. Once the wireless is configured, disconnect the wired connection
5. Try to bring up the web GUI again with the new IP

If your printer is getting a different subnet on wireless then your wireless and wired networks may not be bridged. The default firmware of that router may not be able to bridge them properly, and if that is the case you can replace the firmware with DD-WRT. I checked the model and it should be compatible, but you need to ensure you pick the right firmware for your version of that model of router.

It certainly is peculiar about configuring through the screen on the printer - the advanced features are probably buried somewhere, and you will probably find it easier to go through the web GUI.

Comment: Thanks @BloodyIron - Can you clarify something: Step #2 you say" take the IP of the printer and toss it in your browser"). Would this bring me to my printer's admin GUI? If so, can you point me in the right direction of some instructions for Step #3 (how to configure the printer's wireless connection)? Thanks again!

Comment: @AdamTannon I'm sorry, I tried to look through the manuals and find instructions for this part, but my search so far hasn't turned up instructions just yet. I do know that there is a web gui, but I can't find details on such instructions just yet. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I found this copy of the manual for your router http://www.manualowl.com/m/Netgear/WGR614v7/Manual/73307 and it does not mention WPS anywhere in so I think we can verify that your version does not support it. So you'll need to connect in the old fashioned way.

I looked up the manual for your printer http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02497809.pdf and on page 36 it lays out these instructions:

Traditional Wireless Connection

To connect the product

1. Insert the product Software CD in the computer CD-ROM drive.
2. Follow the instructions on the screen.
   When you are prompted, connect the product to the computer using the USB setup
   cable included in the box. Follow the onscreen prompts to enter your wireless network
   settings. The product will attempt to connect to the network. If the connection fails,
   follow the prompts to correct the problem, and then try again.
3. When the setup is finished, you will be prompted to disconnect the USB cable and
   test the wireless network connection. Once the product connects successfully to the
   network, install the software on each computer that will use the product over the
   network.

In step 2 where it mentions entering your network settings when prompted - that means that you will be asked for the name of your network and the security key.